# Parsing XML output of BLAST results after using Biopython

Tags: python, xml, biopython

I have a FASTA file (test.fasta) which contains many sequences which I aligned with BLASTN using Biopython.

```
import Bio
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML

sequence_data = open("/Users/Desktop/test.fasta").read()
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", sequence_data)
with open('results.xml', 'w') as save_file: 
blast_results = result_handle.read() 
save_file.write(blast_results)
```

The alignment was saved as xml file.
Now, I would like to parse the output of the xml file in order to get the information of the list of all the species found to have a match and possibly I would like to keep only specific species:
Example xml:

```
  <Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
  <Hit_id>gi|2020514704|emb|FR989945.1|</Hit_id>
  <Hit_def>Plebejus argus genome assembly, chromosome: 19</Hit_def>
  <Hit_accession>FR989945</Hit_accession>
  <Hit_len>13381465</Hit_len>
  <Hit_hsps>
    <Hsp>
      <Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
      <Hsp_bit-score>44.5672</Hsp_bit-score>
      <Hsp_score>48</Hsp_score>
      <Hsp_evalue>1.07773</Hsp_evalue>
      <Hsp_query-from>65</Hsp_query-from>
      <Hsp_query-to>99</Hsp_query-to>
      <Hsp_hit-from>12008397</Hsp_hit-from>
      <Hsp_hit-to>12008366</Hsp_hit-to>
      <Hsp_query-frame>1</Hsp_query-frame>
      <Hsp_hit-frame>-1</Hsp_hit-frame>
      <Hsp_identity>31</Hsp_identity>
      <Hsp_positive>31</Hsp_positive>
      <Hsp_gaps>3</Hsp_gaps>
      <Hsp_align-len>35</Hsp_align-len>
      <Hsp_qseq>ACTATCTTTTATTTAGATTAGGTTCAGTATCCCTC</Hsp_qseq>
      <Hsp_hseq>ACTATGTTTTATTT---TTAGGTTCAGTATCCCTC</Hsp_hseq>
  <Hit_num>2</Hit_num>
  <Hit_id>gi|1812775970|gb|CP048843.1|</Hit_id>
  <Hit_def>Crassostrea gigas strain QD chromosome 5</Hit_def>
  <Hit_accession>CP048843</Hit_accession>
  <Hit_len>60957391</Hit_len>
  <Hit_hsps>
    <Hsp>
      <Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
      <Hsp_bit-score>42.7638</Hsp_bit-score>
      <Hsp_score>46</Hsp_score>
      <Hsp_evalue>3.76165</Hsp_evalue>
      <Hsp_query-from>63</Hsp_query-from>
      <Hsp_query-to>95</Hsp_query-to>
      <Hsp_hit-from>42721025</Hsp_hit-from>
      <Hsp_hit-to>42720993</Hsp_hit-to>
      <Hsp_query-frame>1</Hsp_query-frame>
      <Hsp_hit-frame>-1</Hsp_hit-frame>
      <Hsp_identity>29</Hsp_identity>
      <Hsp_positive>29</Hsp_positive>
      <Hsp_gaps>0</Hsp_gaps>
      <Hsp_align-len>33</Hsp_align-len>
      <Hsp_qseq>ATACTATCTTTTATTTAGATTAGGTTCAGTATC</Hsp_qseq>
      <Hsp_hseq>ATACTGTATTTTGTTTAGATTAGGTTCAGTTTC</Hsp_hseq>
```

Expected output would be in this case:

```
Plebejus argus genome assembly, chromosome: 19
Crassostrea gigas strain QD chromosome 5
```

I, addition I would like to keep for example the matches where there is Homo sapiens at line "Hit_def" as well but I have not figured it out yet.
I have written something like this so far:

```
results_handle=open('results.xml')
   for record in NCBIXML.parse(results_handle):
    for alignment in record.alignments:
        for hit in alignment.hits:
            print(hit_def)
```

However, I keep getting some errors:

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

or

> ValueError: More than one record found in handle

Any advice?

Comment: sorry, it is a typo here when I created the questions, not in my code

Comment: There are multiple existing questions dealing with those error messages. Have you look at these?